# Updating large data matrix thread-safely: now using millions of mutexes?

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, mutex, fractals

I was revisting some code I wrote a long time ago, and decided to rewrite it to better make use of threads (and better use of programming in general..).

It is located here: https://github.com/buddhabrot/buddhabrot/blob/master/basic.c:

It is an application that renders a buddhabrot fractal. For reasons out of the scope of this question it is hard to use memoization to optimize this, and basically if you'd profile this, over 99% of the time is spent in the innermost loop that eventually does:

```
buddhabrot[col][row]++;
```

Multiple threads will execute this code. Since incrementing is not thread-safe, I used a specific mutex lock around this part of the memory. So, each addressable location in the buddhabrot memory has a separate mutex.

Now, this is more efficient than using one lock of course (which would definitely make all the threads wait for each other), but it is less memory efficient; it appears the mutexes take some data as well. I am also wondering about other repercussions in the pthreads implementations with millions of mutexes?

I now have two other strategies to consider:

- Use a less dense set of mutex locks, for each "region" in the map. So, a lock for [col/16][row/16], for instance, would only lock a thread if it visits the same region of 16 pixels as another one. The density of the locks could be dynamically adjusted. 
  But as I was modeling this I was wondering if I'm not solving an existing problem that might even be implemented by kernels, and I also can't really find a way to make this without slowing things down. I also thought about "trees of mutexes", but all of this is just too slow inside this loop (to give an indication, after optimizating the order of some maths operations behind the compiler's back I could squeeze out about 30% more processor time). Is there a topic for this, how do I look for mor einformation on "mutex density planning"..?
- Copy the memory for each thread so I don't even have to mutex around it. But this is even more memory-inefficient. It would solve the problem of having millions of mutexes without knowing the repercussions thereof.

So, is there anything else, anything better I could do?

Comment: Having more than say 8-10 threads on a CPU is probably not optimal, unless you have a super computer. Now, the probability that you accidentally update same entry at the same time is minimal, and if it happens, it wont affect the image in a noticeable way at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use atomic increment functions like InterlockedIncrement from the intrin.h on Windows platforms.

```
#include <intrin.h>

#pragma intrinsic(_InterlockedExchangeAdd, _InterlockedIncrement, _InterlockedDecrement, _InterlockedCompareExchange, _InterlockedExchange)
#define InterlockedExchangeAdd _InterlockedExchangeAdd
#define InterlockedIncrement _InterlockedIncrement
#define InterlockedDecrement _InterlockedDecrement
#define InterlockedCompareExchange _InterlockedCompareExchange
#define InterlockedExchange _InterlockedExchange

#pragma intrinsic(abs, fabs, labs, memcmp, memcpy, memset, strcat, strcmp, strcpy, strlen)
#pragma intrinsic(acos, cosh, pow, tanh, asin, fmod, sinh)
#pragma intrinsic(atan, exp, log10, sqrt, atan2, log, sin, tan, cos)
```

This incrementation is atomic and there is no need to have millions of mutex or a global lock on your matrix.

Comment: There is also a Linux alternative, I see. I guess this makes the code less interesting but should work.

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer if the penalty of these API's isn't too high.

Comment: GCC provides the built-in function [__sync_fetch_and_add()](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html) to atomically increment.

Comment: thanks for the hint. im searching for a good solution for linux based for a long time. this will replace the creapy asm code i've fond a long time ago.

Comment: I marked your answer as "the answer", as its performance is similar to using locks everywhere. However, for my application I think I will simply bite the thread-unsafe bullet, because while it produces less accurate results, overall this will not really matter all that much: the odds that two threads visit the same point at exactly the same time are quite small, and if it happens the net effect will be too small to notice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to partition the matrix, so that each thread will only update 1 column. That way they won't get in each others way, and you don't have to lock.

Make a central synchronized queue of all the columns, let each thread go there to get a column number, then it will only update values in that column, and go to the queue for the next column until all are done.

Then the contention will only be on the central queue, wich should be trivial compared to the rest.

Also I guess there will be enough rows in each column, so you wouldn't get false sharing, that would slow you down.

Regards GJ

Comment: That doesn't really work as you have no idea what column will be treated by what thread, due to the chaotic behaviour of the fractal. There is a big difference between the way you'd create a mandelbrot and a buddhabrot. (In a mandelbrot, you want to mark one point which each cycle, in a buddhabrot, each cycle marks several points).

Comment: yeah I just looked through the code some more and spotted that sorry. I there some other predictable way you can partition the work? I don;t have time to fully grasp the code. Strategy #1 for me is always to try and sidestep locking by keeping the threads out of each others way.

Comment: Yeah, the algorithm's a bitch that way.. Maybe it could be partitioned by creating a low-res version or something, and then using that data to "configure" a good partitioning strategy. But it really is a "maybe": I don't know.

Comment: What you could do i have each thread gather it's partial results in its private array, and then add these together after they're all done. So pass 1 would be simply be partitioned around x. Then after all threads have finished, you;d need to add together all the partial results of the threads, but that operation could be parallelized as well. You use a bit more memory though, and do quite some work twice so not sure how much speedup this would actually create.

Answer (score 0):

Your second design is the better choice for exactly the reasons you gave. For rendering a Buddhabrot you want to build up a large matrix of sums. You can avoid memory contention if you let each processor compute its own array and then add its results to a master array every minute or so. That's the only part that requires memory locks, and even that could be avoided by having each thread write to its own file. You do have multiple processors, right? If not, then adding threads will add no benefit.